# How to display a random image from a list, everytime the button is pressed ? C#

Tags: c#, image, button, random

So I'm totally new to C# and I've been building a "Character Generator" for a tabletop RPG. I've assigned a button with the task of generating a new story every time it is pressed. I've downloaded a huge collection of character portraits which I'd like to display in this little app of mine to give some inspiration to the user.

I thought that using a button I could have the app select a different image in the aforementioned list every time it is pressed.

I tried this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        List<String> paths = new List<String>();
        Random random = new Random();
        paths.Add(Project1.Cartes.Portrait);
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = paths[random.Next(0, images.Count - 1)];
```

I get two errors: Project1.Cartes.Portrait is an invalid namespace, and the name "images" does not exist.

I can't mention every image, since there are 500 of them. So I need the app to instead take a random image from a specific location. Any ideas ?

Comment: What exactly is `Project1.Cartes.Portrait` - I think I should be a list of image paths, isnt it?

Comment: Take a look at `Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg")`

Comment: Side note: I think that you are creating the `Random` in the wrong place. Make it a global variable that gets created earlier - creating a random generator every time will actually result in less randomness, not more...

Answer (score 0):

There is insufficient code be definite, however, the errors do indicate exactly what's wrong. For example, where is the variable `images` defined, what type is it, and how it is initialised? Also, I assume that `Project1.Cartes.Portrait` is meant to be a list of paths to the images and should there for be defined as `List<string>` somewhere within the current namespace.

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in my comment, I think the `Project1.Cartes.Portrait` is not what you expect it to be. It should be a `List<string>` to any image files on your disk but it might add the string representation to your `paths`  list.

Something like:

`System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]` (which is definitively not a path to an image file)

instead of the expected:

```
C:\mypath1.jpg
C:\mypath2.jpg
C:\mypath3.jpg
```

So please stop the debugger with a breakpoint **after** `paths.Add(Project1.Cartes.Portrait)` and check if your variable `paths` is what you expect it to be.

**Btw**, if `Project1.Cartes.Portrait`points to a real `List<string>`, you should use `paths.AddRange(...)` instead of `paths.Add(...)` to add the string contents from the list instead of the list itself.

Answer (score 0):

Store the image's locations while your form is loading. Also, you need to remove image use bellow instead.

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = paths[random.Next(0, paths.Count - 1)];
```

Here is the full code. Just need to store the file names in the list.

```
List<String> paths = new List<String>();
    private List<string> GetPaths()
    {
        //You can get it anywhere
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        paths = GetPaths();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = paths[random.Next(0, paths.Count - 1)];
    }
```